# Как сделать кнопку скрыть в плагине Ajax load more для WP?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Как сделать кнопку скрыть в плагине Ajax load more для WP?

Сделать кнопку скрыть после того как все посты раскрыты. Т.е изначально как сделано сейчас стоит кнопка "Посмотреть ещё" После того как я дошел до конца кнопка меняется на "Скрыть все открытые посты" при клике скрывает всё что открыла кроме тех что были изначально

Comment: Уточниете вопрос, надо сделать или скрыть?

Comment: Кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/714041/edit) отредактируйте вопрос, потом можете удалить комментарий. Комментарии мало кто читает.